# MYSQL union with many JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, union, left-join

I'm trying to write a query to fetch a listing from 2 (list1,list2)tables with the same columns. 
Are there any other way to rewrite this code?

```
(SELECT r.id as rid, s.title, u.username  
FROM list1 r 
JOIN drama s ON r.parent_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN image i ON s.image_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.user_id) 

UNION ALL 

(SELECT r.id as rid, s.title, u.username  
FROM list2 r 
JOIN movie s ON r.parent_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN image i ON s.image_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.user_id) 
ORDER BY rid LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong if you do this

```
SELECT r.id as rid, m.title AS movie Title, 
       d.title as DramaTitle, u.username  
FROM list1 r 
INNER JOIN movie m ON r.parent_id = m.id 
INNER JOIN drama d ON r.parent_id = d.id 
LEFT JOIN image i ON s.image_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY r.id LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Well the problem is I have list1, and list2. I'm just making sure if there are any other way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.id as rid, s.title, u.username  
FROM (SELECT l1.id, l1.user_id, l1.parent_id FROM list1 l1 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT l2.id, l2.user_id, l2.parent_id FROM list2 l2) r
INNER JOIN drama s ON r.parent_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN image i ON s.image_id = i.id 
LEFT JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.user_id 
ORDER BY rid 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Oh..I didn't thought of that! That's useful info for my other query, but it still missing the "movie" table. Thanks either way.

Comment: @user you csn do the same union trick on your drama/movie table